# One class with multiple implementation files

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there anything wrong with having a single class (one .h) implemented over multiple source files? I realize that this could be a symptom of too much code in a single class, but is there anything technically wrong with it?

For instance:

Foo.h

```
class Foo
{
   void Read();
   void Write();
   void Run();
}
```

Foo.Read.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::Read()
{
}
```

Foo.Write.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::Write()
{
}
```

Foo.Run.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::Run()
{
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fine. In the end, it will be all linked together.

I have even seen code, where every member function was in a different *.cpp file.

Comment: That would drive me batty.  I'm sure there are occasionally good (or at least decent) reasons to do this, but from the perspective of trying to understand the object model, bleah... to have to jump files to follow methods around.

Comment: If you build a library, splitting every function and global into its own object allows the consumer to link only the bits they reference and no more.  It's annoying to work with, though.

Comment: @ephemient: Why does this matter? Couldn't a linker strip out the functions your don't use? Or is it just for improving link times?

Comment: @ThomasEding The compiler usually places all similar types into the same section.  The linker resolves references and copies sections into the appropriate segments, but usually has no deeper visibility into them, so it cannot split them up.  GCC supports `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` to give everything its own section (on supported targets), allowing the linker to discard with finer granularity, but this causes increased object size, longer linking time, and slower execution.

Answer (score 7):

That is legitimate and it has some (!?) advantages...

If you link your executable with the static library of this class, only the used functions will get in. This is very handy for limited-resource systems.

You can also hide implementation details of certain functions. Two people may implement parts of a class without knowing about each other. Handy for DOD projects.

If you look at any CRT source, you will see the same pattern...

Comment: The point re hiding implementation details for the same class is really stretching it.  If you have a class which can be split so easily, then it should be 2 classes not one.

Comment: @Richard: Well, I just wanted to say that you can do it, you do not have to do it. If the function is so simple, then you may not prefer to create a separate class for it...

Comment: @Richard - eh? - what about a "device" for instance foo::read foo::write foo::ioctl what about the benefits of shorter build times?

Comment: A real advantage is to speed up compile times if by itself the cpp file is HUGE!

Answer (score 5):

Nope, nothing technically wrong with it. The linker will bring all the pieces of Foo together in the final binary.

Comment: The linker complains about duplicate symbols in each compilation unit.

Answer (score 3):

I've been working with the Apache Portable Runtime, which does pretty much this exact thing.  You have a header, say `apr_client.h` and multiple implementation files for the functions in that header -- each file representing one aspect of client operations.  It's not wrong, and it's not really unusual.

> this could be a symptom of too much code in a single class

C++ is not Java, so you don't have to pick your file names according to your class names.

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly valid. All cpp files will be linked together.

This can be useful for, as you said, making a very large implementation file more readable and, since each cpp file is a compilation unit, you could (ab)use that fact. (Unnamed namespaces for example)

Comment: + for mentioning the increased opportunity for internal linkage

Answer (score 1):

yea thats legitmate, and in fact newer languages like C# do that sort of thing of all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There are two points which may be worth considering.

**Class wide optimisations:**

If the compiler has all of the member functions visible to it when its parsing the file (assuming a single TU compiler) then it may be able to perform optimisations between the different member functions.

**Code Review**

If all the definitions for a class are in the same TU, then this makes manual code review easier.  If the definitions are split into different TUs, this significantly increases the effort required for a manual review as the appropriate files need to be searched for, with constant flicking between windows to get the "whole" picture.